# Access all fields of an EntityType

Tags: symfony

I have a form (new Order) that contains a CollectionType field where the entry_type is another form (Product (Name and quantity) ) which contain a EntityType field (A dropdown select) with a IntegerType field.

I'm using Symfony prototype to allow multiple add of this form (add many product to an order ), but I want to access the price of each product displayed so I can calculate the final amount of this order.

OrderForm:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
       ->add('client', EntityType::class, array(
           'class' => 'AppBundle:Client',
           'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
               return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                   ->orderBy('u.raison', 'ASC');
           },
           'choice_label' => 'raison',

       ))


        ->add('ligne', CollectionType::class, array(
            'entry_type' => BCitemsFormType::class,
            'allow_add'    => true,
            'allow_delete'    => true,
            'by_reference' => false,

        ))

    ;

}
```

ProductLine:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('produit', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Produit',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.libele', 'ASC');
            },
            'choice_label' => 'libele',


        ))

        ->add('quantity', IntegerType::class, [
            'attr' => ['min' => 1],
            'label' => 'Quantité',
        ])
        ;

}
```

View where I'm displaying The ProductLine Form:

```
<div class="form-group" id="form_ref">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3">Produits</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="input-icon right">
                  <i class="" data-original-title="" id="icone_ref"></i>

                   <ul class="tags" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(bcForm.ligne.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}" >


                    </ul>




                 </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

When I add a product Line, I get a list of my products with name field in the choice_label, I want to display the price also or any others fields of my entity Product.

Comment: where do you from ?i think i know you

Comment: Im from Tunisia

Comment: I think you everytime you select a product a javascript function will calculate the amount and display it but before you to get the price value for every time you select an object ,try to dump your bcForm , try to dump it ,maybe you will find the id for each product , the use it onelect product to get the price ,here use your logic .
by the way comment here do not post an answer only if you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer , the problem is not only to display the price , i need to check wich value of my Product List is selected and get the right price , with prototype the code is generated automaticly so i cant know the name of the Select element .